# How to dump default timestamp value with mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have following column in my database:

```
MariaDB [mydb]> desc MY_TABLE;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
...
| SOME_DATE      | timestamp    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
...
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I dump database with `mysqldump -p -u myuser mydb` it defines `MY_TABLE` as:

```
CREATE TABLE `MY_TABLE` (
  ...
  `SOME_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL,
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

So when I load dump back:

```
MariaDB [mydb_after_loading_dump]> desc MY_TABLE;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
...
| SOME_DATE      | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
...
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

How to force `mysqldump` to dump correct default value of `SOME_DATE` ?

server version: `10.1.14-MariaDB-1~trusty`

mysql version: `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.14-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`

mysqldump version: `mysqldump  Ver 10.16 Distrib 10.1.14-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`

Comment: If the column doesn't allow null values, you can't use `NULL` as the default value.

Comment: I can - first snippet comes from running database and it's used to turn off automatic updates of this field ("Disabling automatic properties" paragraph at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/timestamp/)

Comment: "Specify the timestamp column with a constant default value" - apparently `NULL` meets "constant default value" criteria.

Comment: But if I read the rest of it, it seems to say that assigning `NULL` to a column with the `NOT NULL` attribute actually means to assign `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Maybe just make that an explicit default?

Comment: When you create new rows in this table, what do you actually get as the default for the `SOME_DATE` column?

Comment: I don't use its default value, `SOME_COLUMN` is always filled (with non null value) while inserting - default `null` is only to turn off automatic field updates.

Comment: You don't need that. From the documentation: **If you specify a DEFAULT clause, but not an ON UPDATE clause, the timestamp value will not automatically change when an UPDATE statement is executed.** Since it has `DEFAULT 0000-00-00` but no `ON UPDATE` option, automatic updates are disable.

Comment: What version of mysqldump are you using?  What version of mysql/mariadb will you be loading the dump into?  (The handling of timestamp changed in the area of defaults.)

Comment: @Barmar, I do need correctly restored default value: I run clients with `SQL_MODE=TRADITIONAL` (which forbids zero dates among others) and this default of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` cause error when creating index involving `SOME_DATE` column. @Rick James: versions are described in question.

Answer (score 2):

The table must have been created when the server was running with the option `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=on`. The explanation why it couldn't happen otherwise is below.

> **UPDATE:**
>
> As Radek Postołowicz noted in the comments, the same effect can be
>   also achieved with `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=off` by running an `ALTER` statement explicitly dropping a `DEFAULT`
>   clause without changing `NULL`-ability.

Now the server must be running with `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=off` (default). So, when you dump the table structure, it is dumped correctly, just as it was created. But when you are trying to restore it, the impicit logic caused by `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=off` kicks in. Your table apparently has another `TIMESTAMP` column earlier in the structure, so `SOME_DATE` does not get `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`s, but it does get the default value.

If you really need to restore it in the exact same way, you'll have to set `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp` back to `on` (which will require the server restart). The question is, why do you need it? If you don't use the default value as you say in the comments, it shouldn't matter whether the column has one or not.

---

**Why the table could only be created with `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=on`**

When the server runs with `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=off` (default), this table structure cannot be created unless the code is hacked:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT @@explicit_defaults_for_timestamp;
+-----------------------------------+
| @@explicit_defaults_for_timestamp |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 0 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

If you don't specify column attributes, first timestamp is created with auto-update properties, other ones with default 0:

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t1 (ts1 TIMESTAMP, ts2 TIMESTAMP);
MariaDB [test]> desc t1;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| ts1   | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| ts2   | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Same if you specify `NOT NULL`:

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t4 (ts1 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ts2 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
MariaDB [test]> desc t4;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| ts1   | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| ts2   | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

If you set `DEFAULT` attribute, you'll see it in the description:

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t2 (ts1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0, ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0);
MariaDB [test]> desc t2;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| ts1   | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| ts2   | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

You cannot give `NOT NULL`able columns `NULL`s as defaults:

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t5 (ts1 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL, ts2 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL);
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'ts1'
```

And if you make columns `NULL`-able with `NULL` values, you'll see them as such:

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t3 (ts1 TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL, ts2 TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL);
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ts1   | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ts2   | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

But if you have `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=on`, you **can** get the exact table structure by using the most simple variation of `CREATE` statement:

```
MariaDB [test]> select @@explicit_defaults_for_timestamp;
+-----------------------------------+
| @@explicit_defaults_for_timestamp |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 1 |
+-----------------------------------+

MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t6 (ts1 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ts2 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
MariaDB [test]> desc t6;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ts1   | timestamp | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ts2   | timestamp | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Indeed: restoring with `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=1` did the trick. Unluckily I can't relay on it (I can't restart server). However you are wrong with: "The table must have been created when the server was running with the option `explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=on`": it is possible to achieve it with `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE CHANGE SOME_DATE SOME_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ALTER COLUMN SOME_DATE DROP DEFAULT;`

Comment: "The question is, why do you need it?", As I wrote in comment to the question: I run clients with `SQL_MODE=TRADITIONAL` (which forbids zero dates among others) and this default of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` cause error when creating index involving `SOME_DATE` column.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense then to give it a valid default value? A non-null column without a default (in general, not necessarily for timestamps), while possible, is a bit questionable, I expect with the current tendency to stricter  modes they might cause you even more troubles in future.

Comment: I've added an update to point at your finding about ALTER statement.

Comment: "...while possible, is a bit questionable, I expect with the current tendency to stricter modes they might cause you even more troubles in future." Yes, I decided to migrate to `datetime` after all.